# Limit on the number of arguments to main in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Is there a limit on the number of arguments that we pass to `main()` in C? As you all know, it is defined as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

When I call the program, I can pass arguments like so:

```
$ prog.exe arg1 arg2 arg3.....argn
```

Is there an upper bound in the number of argument that we may supply to `main()` in this way?

Comment: See also [To check the E2BIG condition in `exec()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559403/to-check-the-e2big-error-condition-in-exec).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there is no limit imposed by the ISO C99 standard. If you're using the "blessed" `main` form (of which there are two):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]);
```

then you will be limited to the maximum size of a signed integer (implementation-dependent but guaranteed to be at least 2<sup>15</sup>-1 or 32,767).

Of course, you could even have *more* than that since the standard specifically allows for non-blessed `main` forms (for example, one that takes a `long` as the count).

The standard mandates how the arguments are stored and things like `argv[argc]` having to be NULL, but it does not directly limit the quantity.

Of course, there will be a limit in practice but this will depend entirely on the implementation and environment. However, if you have to ask, then you're probably doing [something wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx).

Most tools would place a truly large number of arguments into a response file (say `args.txt`) then pass a single argument like:

```
my_prog @args.txt
```

which gets around arbitrary limits on argument quantity and size.

Comment: By "non-blessed" do you mean the Standard allows for implementations to 'work' without an Operating System?

Comment: No, not entirely. You can still use one of the two canonical forms in a non-OS environment even if there are no arguments passed in. `main` isn't usually the start point so the startup code could push a zero `argc` and NULL `argv[0]` before calling `main`. I mean that ISO allows for other variants of main, for example the `{argc, argv, envp}` variant from UNIX where the environment is passed in as well.

Comment: +1 for providing some Windows answers. @pmg: No, it means the Standard allows OSes/environments to define other non-portable formats for `main`.

Comment: Ah ok. ISO allows variants of `main` but "in some other implementation-defined manner", so by using a different `main` prototype you're locking yourself to a specific implementation.

Comment: Yes, at a bare minimum, a compiler must provide the two canonical forms. Anything else is optional and implementation-defined so you're right - you'll probably be tying yourself to that implementation (or compatible ones).

Answer (score 16):

According to the POSIX spec for [`exec`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), there is a macro `ARG_MAX` defined in [`<limits.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) which defines the maximum number of bytes for the arguments + environment variables.

But since C doesn't define anything about that, no, there isn't an inherent cross-platform limit. You have to consult your OS manual if it doesn't define that macro.

Comment: Re: `exec()` syscall. OSs simply for sanity reasons limit how much memory they would have to transfer from the old process memory image into the new one being created. Since the transfer happens in kernel, there has to be limit to avoid user processes depleting kernel memory (imagine the [fork/shell bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#Example_fork_bombs)). On Windows that shouldn't matter, since the old process remains, but IIRC they limit it too to 32K.

Comment: The value provided by `limit.h` could be lower than the actual value supported by the OS and may be intended to be used as a way of saying "well, we know that it can be at least this big".  When setting up arguments for `exec` this may be good enough, but I wouldn't rely on that value for the size of the arguments that a program could actually be passed by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think so. While there may not be a theoretical limit, the computer probably can't handle 1.5 million arguments. Is there any particular reason you need to know this? I wouldn't recommend using command line arguments for thing other than options, file parameters, ect...

Comment: It was because of this discussion I was having with a collegue of mine. My collegue was asked this question in an interview. I was wondering if it might be limited by the size of the stack or by the size of an int as andrew mentioned but I ain't sure of any of those.

Comment: @Ravi: They don't go on the stack. It's more likely limited by the process memory layout or other OS configuration. You could theoretically implement a *new* C environment other than the native platform ABI with more capabilities.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The space for arguments is often allocated on the process's initial stack.  It's easy to put them there because the OS has to set up this area anyway, and it does allow the size of the arguments to vary or grow in future versions of the OS because it doesn't rely on the size of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit explicit in C itself. This is an example of a behavior not defined in the language but rather the implementation. Remember that the language itself is different than it's implementation, subsequent libraries, IDE's, etc.