# Can Perl manage millions of files?

Tags: perl

I like to make my own scripts to plot some data in bash.
Anyway for now I have thousands of files that I want to "rename", "edit"
and much more.

When I try to manage those files, the shell says something like

```
$Arguments list too long
```

I'm wondering if Perl can manage such amount of files?

Comment: You're probably hitting a bash limit. Use the shell construct `find ... -print0 | xargs -n25 perl script.pl ` and you should be sorted

Comment: @hd1, It's not a shell limit -- it's a system limit -- and you can use `find ... -exec perl script.pl {} +` in a GNU system (e.g. linux). Of course both `xargs` and `find -exec` assume processing X files is the same as processing Y files then processing Z files (where X=Y+Z)

Comment: You can use `getconf ARG_MAX` to determine the argument list size limit.  On Mac OS X 10.8.5 (as Jonathan Leffler mentioned) this returns 262144 or 262144/1024 = 256 KiB.

Comment: It would help to see how you are calling the program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an upper limit to the length of the arguments plus environment that you are allowed on Unix.  For many modern versions of Unix, that limit is around 256 KiB — for other versions, it may be less.

This is a not a limit of the shell, per se, nor of Perl nor any other program, but rather a limit imposed by the Unix kernel.

If handling files one at a time, Perl can handle many millions of files in total.  The difficulty is conveying the list of files to Perl.  You can write the names to a file and tell Perl which file to read.  You can use `xargs`.  You have to worry about what marks the end of a file name.  The safe answer is a null byte; it is the only character that cannot appear in a pathname in Unix.  You'd find it easiest to use POSIX function [`getdelim()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) to read such lines.  Using a newline is conventional but not 100%; a file name can contain a newline, leading to confusion.

You could also have Perl generate the lists of files itself, by reading directories (piecemeal, but doesn't drag millions of names into memory all at once) or by using functions such as [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).

See also [SO 18559403: How big an argument list is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18559403/).

This code can help you determine the limit on your argument list; it is a refinement of an answer I gave to the cross-referenced question. It tells me 256 KiB on Mac OS X 10.8.5.  On an archaic Linux 2.6 kernel, I got a limit of 128 KiB.

```
/* SO 18559403: How big an argument list is allowed */

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char **environ;  /* Sometimes in <unistd.h> */

enum { BYTES_PER_KIBIBYTE = 1024 };
enum { BYTES_PER_MEBIBYTE = BYTES_PER_KIBIBYTE * BYTES_PER_KIBIBYTE };
enum { E_GOT_E2BIG =  37 };
enum { E_NOT_E2BIG = 219 };

enum { R_TOO_LARGE = +1, R_TOO_SMALL = -1 };

static char *print_kib(int size, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    snprintf(buffer, buflen, "%d (%d KiB)", size, size / BYTES_PER_KIBIBYTE);
    return buffer;
}

static int test_arg_size(int size)
{
    char buffer[32];
    int result = R_TOO_SMALL;
    assert(size % 8 == 0);
    fflush(0);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fork at size %s\n",
                print_kib(size, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        int self = getpid();
        printf("Child: %d\n", self);
        char *args[10] = { "ls" };
        size_t bytes_per_arg = size / 8;
        for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++)
        {
            args[j] = malloc(bytes_per_arg);
            if (args[j] == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate argument space at size %s\n",
                        print_kib(size, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
                exit(E_NOT_E2BIG);
            }
            memset(args[j], j + '0', bytes_per_arg - 1);
            args[j][bytes_per_arg - 1] = '\0';
        }

        /* Close standard I/O channels so executed command doesn't spew forth */
        int dev_null = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
        if (dev_null < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open /dev/null for reading and writing\n");
            exit(E_NOT_E2BIG);
        }
        int dev_stderr = dup(2);
        if (dev_stderr < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to dup() standard error\n");
            exit(E_NOT_E2BIG);
        }
        close(0);
        dup(dev_null);
        close(1);
        dup(dev_null);
        close(2);
        dup(dev_null);
        close(dev_null);

        /* Execute ls on big file names -- error is ENAMETOOLONG */
        execvp(args[0], args);

        /* Reinstate standard error so we can report failure */
        dup2(dev_stderr, 2);
        int errnum = errno;
        if (errnum == E2BIG)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d: got E2BIG (%d: %s) at size %s\n",
                    self, errnum, strerror(errnum),
                    print_kib(size, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
            exit(E_GOT_E2BIG);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: got errno %d (%s) at size %s\n",
                self, errnum, strerror(errnum),
                print_kib(size, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
        exit(E_NOT_E2BIG);
    }
    else
    {
        int self = getpid();
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) != -1)
        {
            if (!WIFEXITED(status))
                printf("%d: child %d died with exit status 0x%.4X", self, corpse, status);
            else
            {
                int statval = WEXITSTATUS(status);
                printf("%d: child %d died with exit status %d: ", self, corpse, statval);
                switch (statval)
                {
                case E_GOT_E2BIG:
                    printf("success: got E2BIG");
                    result = R_TOO_LARGE;
                    break;
                case E_NOT_E2BIG:
                    printf("failed: indeterminate error in child");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("command exited with status 1 - it worked");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("unknown: unexpected exit status %d", statval);
                    break;
                }
            }
            printf(" at size %s\n", print_kib(size, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

static int env_size(void)
{
    int size = 0;
    for (char **ep = environ; *ep != 0; ep++)
        size += strlen(*ep) + 1;
    return size;
}

int main(void)
{
    int env = env_size();
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = BYTES_PER_MEBIBYTE;

    /* Binary search -- the kilobyte slop means termination does not have to be accurate */
    while (lo + 1 * BYTES_PER_KIBIBYTE < hi)
    {
        int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        if (test_arg_size(mid) == R_TOO_LARGE)
            hi = mid;
        else
            lo = mid;
    }

    char buffer1[32];
    char buffer2[32];
    printf("Environment size = %d\n", env);
    printf("Best guess: maximum argument size in range %s to %s\n",
           print_kib(lo + env, buffer1, sizeof(buffer1)),
           print_kib(hi + env, buffer2, sizeof(buffer2)));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Avoid placing the file names on the command line if you are going to have lots of filenames and hence hit the shells limits.

In addition I would avoid xargs as this will slow things down due to firing up Perl multiple times.

The best solution is to use the find library i.e. http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest thing that you could do is to store the files in file and process that file in your script.

Like:

```
$ find (your find command) > /tmp/files
$ your_prg.pl /tmp/files

#!perl
my $filelist = shift @ARGV;
open(my $fh,'<',$filelist) or die $!;
while (my $filename = <$fh>){
   chomp $filename;

   ### do whatever want to do with the file

}
```

Comment: This works fine as long as the file names themselves do not contain any newlines.  That's a rare occurrence (mercifully), but not impossible.

Comment: I'm guessing you could do something like `$/ = "\0";` and use `find -print0` to eliminate that problem...?

Comment: It's Perl — TIMTOWTDI :D  Yes, it can be handled; you just have to decide whether to worry about it.  When was the last time you encountered someone who intentionally created a file name containing a newline? … Yes; except when I'm testing code to see that it handles such file names, I don't run into them either.