# The maximum summarized size of argv, envp, argc (command line arguments) is always far from the ARG_MAX limit

Tags: c, linux, bash, linux-kernel, execve

I wrote a program which should calculate the total size of arguments passed to `execve` system call.

I have tested this program with maximum size of arguments, expecting that the "*Argument list too long*" error will be happen only when a `ARG_MAX` limit has exceeded. In my opinion, the maximum total size of command line should be as close as possible to `ARG_MAX` limit, that is no additional argument (filename) can be added without exceeding of this limit.

But I see another behavior: the number of "unused" bytes fluctuates in unpredictable manner while environment and program name stays unchanged, only the number of arguments are changing.

**The questions:**

- the counting program is incorrect and missing some values? Why "*Argument list too long*" happens earlier than it should?
- this is a normal behavior and unused bytes are type of memory padding/alignment/whatever? Where this behavior is mentioned in a kernel source then? I have read [linux/fs/exec.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/16f73eb02d7e1765ccab3d2018e0bd98eb93d973/fs/exec.c#L213) and haven't saw something answering to my question.

**Program**

The counting algorithm is next:

size of `argv` + size of `envp` + size of `argc`

1. The `argv` is array of pointers to strings (pointer to `char`), so loop through this array and add to a result the lengths of strings, keeping in mind that every is ended by NULL byte. Then add their pointers to the result - the size of pointer is 8 byte. Thus: `the number of pointers * 8` + `lengths of strings (each with a NULL byte)`
2. Almost the same story with `envp` - string lengths with NULL byte and pointers. But the last pointer is signalizing to the end of array by pointing to the NULL byte, so add it to the result `8 bytes + 1 bytes`.
3. The `argc` is simple `int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    size_t char_ptr_size = sizeof(char *);
    // The arguments array total size calculation
    size_t arg_strings_size = 0;
    size_t string_len = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        // Every string ends up with a nullbyte, so the 1 byte is added
        string_len = strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
        arg_strings_size += string_len;
//      printf("%zu:\t%s\n", string_len, argv[i]);
    }

    size_t argv_size = arg_strings_size + argc * char_ptr_size;

    printf( "arg strings size: %zu\n"
            "number of pointers to strings %i\n\n"
            "argv size:\t%zu + %i * %zu = %zu\n",
             arg_strings_size,
             argc,
             arg_strings_size,
             argc,
             char_ptr_size,
             argv_size
        );

    // The enviroment variables array total size calculation
    size_t env_size = 0;
    for (char **env = envp; *env != 0; env++) {
        char *thisEnv = *env;
        // Every string ends up with a nullbyte, so the 1 byte is added
        env_size += strlen(thisEnv) + 1 + char_ptr_size;
    }

    // The last element of "envp" is a pointer to the NULL byte, so size of pointer and 1 is added
    printf("envp size:\t%zu\n", env_size + char_ptr_size + 1);

    size_t overall = argv_size + env_size + sizeof(argc);

    printf( "\noverall (argv_size + env_size + sizeof(argc)):\t"
            "%zu + %zu + %zu = %zu\n",
             argv_size,
             env_size,
             sizeof(argc),
             overall);
    // Find ARG_MAX by system call
    long arg_max = sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX);

    printf("ARG_MAX: %li\n\n", arg_max);
    printf("Number of \"unused bytes\": ARG_MAX - overall = %li\n\n", arg_max - (long) overall);

    return 0;
}
```

**Testing**

**1 byte filenames** - 975 bytes unused.

```
$ ./program $(yes A | head -n 209222) # 209223 will cause "Argument list too long"

arg strings size: 418454
number of pointers to strings 209223

argv size:  418454 + 209223 * 8 = 2092238
envp size:  3944

overall (argv_size + env_size + sizeof(argc)):  2092238 + 3935 + 4 = 2096177
ARG_MAX: 2097152

Number of "unused bytes": ARG_MAX - overall = 975
```

**2 bytes filenames** - 3206 bytes unused.

```
$ ./program $(yes AA | head -n 189999)

arg strings size: 570007
number of pointers to strings 190000

argv size:  570007 + 190000 * 8 = 2090007
envp size:  3944

overall (argv_size + env_size + sizeof(argc)):  2090007 + 3935 + 4 = 2093946
ARG_MAX: 2097152

Number of "unused bytes": ARG_MAX - overall = 3206
```

**3 bytes filenames** - 2279 bytes unused.

```
$ ./program $(yes AAA | head -n 174243)

arg strings size: 696982
number of pointers to strings 174244

argv size:  696982 + 174244 * 8 = 2090934
envp size:  3944

overall (argv_size + env_size + sizeof(argc)):  2090934 + 3935 + 4 = 2094873
ARG_MAX: 2097152

Number of "unused bytes": ARG_MAX - overall = 2279
```

This question is part of my another question: [How calculate the number of files which can be passed as arguments to some command for batch processing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609574/109397)

Comment: *envp* is not a C standard. And to answer your question, "How calculate the number of files which can be passed as arguments to some command for batch processing?", you better read this interesting article: https://serverfault.com/questions/163371/linux-command-line-character-limit In short, the limit is usually system specific.

Comment: I guess I'd ask the question: _Does this scale?_ What would you do if you had to process 100,000,000 files [and could _not_ use an `xarg` style solution]? There are a number of [standard] programs that already solve this issue.

Comment: @CraigEstey No, the question is purely theoretical - for educational purposes.

Comment: You can find some code in my answer to the SO question [To check the E2BIG condition in exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559403/to-check-the-e2big-error-condition-in-exec).  It goes around establishing the size by trial and error (and binary search) to get to within a kilobyte or so of the space available.  It's also available  in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `e2big.c` in the [src/so-1855-9403](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-1855-9403) sub-directory.

Comment: While the C standard does not mandate the `envp` argument to `main()`, it does recognize it as a common extension — see Annex J [§J.5.1 Environment arguments](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.1).  On Linux, that argument is available, and the question is tagged with Linux.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** The issues are caused by `ASLR` (address space layout randomization) See the **UPDATE** section below [after my original answer] for an explanation

---

As paladin mentioned, this is system specific. For example, for `freebsd`, the number is much less.

A few things to note [under linux] ...

`ARG_MAX` is defined as `131072` [which is 32 4K pages].

`_SC_ARG_MAX` returns `2097152` [which is 2MB]

The claim in `bits/param.h`:

> The kernel headers define ARG_MAX.  The value is wrong, though.

However, as measured, it seems to be right.

From the code in `linux/fs/exec.c` it checks against the [hardwired] value of `ARG_MAX`. It also checks against `_STK_LIM` [which is 8MB] and `rlimit(RLIMIT_STACK)` [which defaults to `_STK_LIM`]

The best way to get the real limit is to count the size of `argv` and `envp`, which you do. But, you don't account for the size of the `NULL` pointer at the end of each.

---

I'd do a binary search on the amount of data that gets passed [checking for `E2BIG`]:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <linux/limits.h>
long arg_lgx = ARG_MAX;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/param.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int pgm_argc;
char **pgm_argv;
char **pgm_envp;

int opt_s;
char *opt_R;

size_t envlen;
size_t totlen;
long arg_max;
size_t lo;
size_t hi;

int status;

size_t
argvlen(char **argv)
{
    size_t totlen = 0;

    for (;  *argv != NULL;  ++argv) {
        size_t slen = strlen(*argv);

        totlen += slen;
        totlen += 1;

        totlen += sizeof(char *);
    }

    totlen += sizeof(char *);

    return totlen;
}

size_t
lenall(int argc,char **argv,char **envp)
{
    size_t totlen = 0;

    size_t avlen = argvlen(argv);
    avlen += sizeof(argv);
    totlen += avlen;

    size_t envlen = argvlen(envp);
    envlen += sizeof(envp);
    totlen += envlen;

    totlen += sizeof(argc);

    return totlen;
}

char *
strmake(size_t explen)
{
    char *bp;
    char *buf;

    explen -= sizeof(char *);
    explen -= 1;

    buf = malloc(explen + 1);

    for (bp = buf;  explen > 0;  --explen, ++bp)
        *bp = (explen % 26) + 'A';

    *bp = 0;

    return buf;
}

void
doexec(size_t totlen)
{
    size_t explen;
    int sverr;
    char *argv[4];

    explen = totlen;
    explen -= envlen;

    argv[0] = pgm_argv[0];
    argv[1] = "-s";
    argv[2] = strmake(explen);
    argv[3] = NULL;

    pid_t pid = fork();

    do {
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("%zu %zu %zu\n",lo,totlen,hi);

            execvpe(argv[0],argv,pgm_envp);
            sverr = errno;

            status = sverr << 8;
            printf("%8.8X %d -- %s\n",status,sverr,strerror(sverr));

            exit(sverr);
            break;
        }

        waitpid(pid,&status,0);

        free(argv[2]);
    } while (0);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv,char **envp)
{
    char *cp;
    size_t totlen;

    pgm_argc = argc;
    pgm_argv = argv;
    pgm_envp = envp;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    envlen = argvlen(envp);

    arg_max = sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX);

#if 0
    totlen = lenall(argc,argv,envp);
    printf("%zu\n",totlen);
#endif

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    //printf("main: '%s'\n",*argv);

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 's':
            opt_s = 1;
            break;
        case 'R':
            opt_R = cp;
            break;
        }
    }

    // slave just exits
    if (opt_s)
        exit(0);

    if (opt_R != NULL) {
        size_t Rsize = strtol(opt_R,&cp,10);

        switch (*cp) {
        case 'K':
        case 'k':
            Rsize *= 1024;
            break;
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
            Rsize *= 1024;
            Rsize *= 1024;
            break;
        }

        printf("stksiz: %zu (ARG)\n",Rsize);

        struct rlimit rlim;
        getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&rlim);
        printf("stksiz: %lu %lu (OLD)\n",rlim.rlim_cur,rlim.rlim_max);

        rlim.rlim_cur = Rsize;
        setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&rlim);

        getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK,&rlim);
        printf("stksiz: %lu %lu (NEW)\n",rlim.rlim_cur,rlim.rlim_max);
    }

    printf("arg_lgx: %zu\n",arg_lgx);
    printf("arg_max: %zu\n",arg_max);
    printf("envlen: %zu\n",envlen);

    lo = 32;
    hi = 100000000;

    while (lo < hi) {
        size_t mid = (lo + hi) / 2;

        doexec(mid);

        if (status == 0)
            lo = mid + 1;
        else
            hi = mid - 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
arg_lgx: 131072
arg_max: 2097152
envlen: 3929
32 50000016 100000000
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
32 25000023 50000015
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
32 12500027 25000022
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
32 6250029 12500026
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
32 3125030 6250028
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
32 1562530 3125029
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
32 781280 1562529
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
32 390655 781279
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
32 195343 390654
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
32 97687 195342
97688 146515 195342
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
97688 122101 146514
122102 134308 146514
134309 140411 146514
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
134309 137359 140410
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
134309 135833 137358
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
134309 135070 135832
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
134309 134689 135069
134690 134879 135069
134880 134974 135069
134975 135022 135069
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
134975 134998 135021
134999 135010 135021
00000700 7 -- Argument list too long
134999 135004 135009
135005 135007 135009
135008 135008 135009
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The variation you're seeing is due to `ASLR` (address space layout randomization). It randomizes the starting addresses of various sections of a program/process as a security mitigation.

There are a few methods to disable ASLR:

1. System wide by changing `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`
2. A program can do it for a child process using the `personality` syscall.
3. The `setarch` program uses the syscall method to invoke a subprogram in a manner similar to a shell.

See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization and [Disable randomization of memory addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194666/disable-randomization-of-memory-addresses)

ASLR sets random starting positions for starting/highest stack address, `envp`, `argv`, and the starting stack position/frame given to `main`.

What appears to be "unused" space is a function of that placement and padding/alignment. So, the space really isn't unused (i.e. potentially usable).

Even with the same exact arguments passed to a child the addresses change with ASLR on.

I knew about ASLR, but wasn't sure if it applied here (on the stack) [at first].

Before I figured out the connection, I enhanced my program to look at and compare some of these various addresses and offsets between them.

With ASLR on, however, if we run the child multiple [*many ;-)*] times, even if two or more runs happen to match on some of the same starting addresses (e.g. highest stack address) other parameters can still vary independently.

So, I enhanced the program to optionally disable ASLR via the `personality` syscall, and, when disabled, each run has the same placement and offsets.

My refactored program is at the limit of what can be posted in a code block here, so here's a link: https://pastebin.com/gYwRFvcv [I don't normally do this--see the section below as to why].

There are many options to this program as I performed a number of experiments before reaching my conclusions.

The `-A` option will disable ASLR. Consider running it with `-x100000 -Ma@` [with/without] the `-A`.

Another good combo is adding `-L` to above. This overrides the binary search in favor of a single argument length that is within a reasonable size.

See the comments in the code for more information.

With that, you can experiment further if necessary [or give you some ideas] to modify your own program.

Comment: Good program, clear and understandable code. I was going to write something similar - move all logic into pure `C`, without `bash` usage. But it is still unclear what causes **the number of "unused" bytes fluctuates in unpredictable manner**  or I miss something? Why the number of unused bytes is not coherent: 975, 3206, 2279 for 'A', 'AA', 'AAA' respectively?

Comment: I have not read your new code yet, but I have tried to run my program with and without **ASLR** and have seen a little difference in "unused bytes": `setarch $(uname -m) -R ./program $(yes AA | head -n 189988)` gives **3321** bytes and `./program $(yes AA | head -n 189999)` gives **3207**. A few additional filenames is caused by difference in the length of the command (`setarch x86_64 -R` is 18 bytes long). Thus, disabling **ASLR** has no effect to available memory.  Also, the fluctuation of unused bytes depending on argument size is left as well: **966** with 'A' and **3207** with 'AA'.

Comment: I have expected that with disabled **ASLR** the fluctuation will gone (all starts from the same memory address every time) and it can be calculated in advance how much filenames the command can take. For example, if I know `ARG_MAX` and `enviroment size`, I can subtract the  `enviroment size` from `ARG_MAX` and get the allowable arguments length, then I can create a line of characters (all intricacies with pointers and NULL bytes are omitted for simplicity) equal to this value, pass it to some program and don’t get _”Argument list too long”_.