# true properties of argv command line argument container

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I understand that command line arguments are pointed by the string pointers in the argv [] array. i.e. argv [0] contains a pointer to the name of the program and argv [1] a pointer to the very first command line argument.

But I noticed a very different application of argv on the internet and is written below. I have compiled it successfully and it print out the second arguments third character.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
    int main(int argc , char *argv []) {        
        printf("%c\n", argv [1][2]);                
        return 0; }
```

I have two question arising from this use.

What is the true dimension of argv? does it stop at two or is there more?

I have noticed it the code that the programer has used %c to access and print the pointed content. Now, we can always parse a pointer (a string pointer) to %s and expect it to print out the set of chars untill null terminator.

upto the best of my understanding %c can only be used if the array it self contains the character.

i.e.

```
char yadhavan [] = yadhavan is a boy;
 printf ("%c", yadhavan [3]);
```

Could someone please explain how %c has been used with a pointer array?

A little more explanation is always more than welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the true dimension of argv? does it stop at two or is there more?

`argc` tells you the argument count (or the dimension of `argv` as you put it). In other words, the number of strings in `argv` is equal to `argc`. So, `argv` can contain more than two strings if multiple arguments are provided. For example, if I were to execute some command like

```
$ foo file1 file2 ...
```

`argv` would look like

```
argv[0] = "foo\0"
argv[1] = "file1\0"
argv[2] = "file2\0"
...
```

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean/3024202#3024202) for more details on `argc` vs `argv`.

> Could someone please explain how %c has been used with a pointer array?

First, `%s` is used for printing strings. `%c` is used for printing a single character. Second, `argv` is an array of strings, and a string is simply an array of characters (`char`). So, `argv` is really an array of arrays of chars. So, when you see

```
printf("%c\n", argv[1][2]);
```

the code is printing out the third character of the second argument in `argv`. So, if I were to execute the command

```
$ foo bar
```

`argc` and `argv` would look like

```
argc = 2
argv[0] = "foo\0"
argv[1] = "bar\0"
argv[1][0] = 'b'
argv[1][1] = 'a'
argv[1][2] = 'r'
argv[1][3] = '\0' // null terminator
```

Answer (score 3):

`argv` is of type `char*[]` and holds several strings(command line arguments).
 
`argv[i]` is of type `char*` and holds a string. 
`argv[i][j]` is of type `char` and holds a character.

> What is the true dimension of argv? Does it stop at two or is there more?

It depends on how many command line arguments there are.

> Could someone please explain how `%c` has been used with a pointer array?

One can declare `char` pointers and make them point to strings or just use a `char` array and hold the string:

```
char* str="string";
```

Or

```
char str[]="string";
```

In both of these ways it is possible to refer a character using:

```
printf("%c",str[3]);
```

`argv` is actually an array of `char*`. So, it is possible to refer a single character from it.

Comment: how does  querying  argv [i] [j] suddenly make the pointer array behave like a char array?

Comment: `argv[i][j]` isn't a pointer or a `char` array. It is a `char`.

Comment: but argv was defined by me as a pointer array in the beginning of my code. How did it become a char array? im a little confused here.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

char *argv [] is array of pointers and this acts as a two dimention array, it can't contains more than 2D. So the data in 'argv' is very similar to 2D, but limitations are not specified. You can check in the below link:[Limit on the number of arguments to main in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724369/limit-on-the-number-of-arguments-to-main-in-c)

```
#include <stdio.h>  
   int main(int argc , char *argv []) {        
    printf("%c\n", argv [1][2]);                
    return 0; }
```

Here char *argv [] is very similar to

```
Char argv[][]  //with no argument limitation.
```